# R is not Artinian but R/J is semisimple

Tags: ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

Can there be a ring R (with 1) such that R is not Artinian but R/J is semisimple where J is the Jacobson radical?

I know if R is Artinian, then R/J is semisimple. That's why I was wondering about the converse.

I've tried working with some non Artinian rings like $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[x]$ but it didn't solve my question.

Comment: Such rings $R$ are known as semilocal rings.

Comment: Okay. Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: [Here is the DaRT query for those results](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=24&L=63l&L=63r). Several local domains are among the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, any local domain satisfies the desired criterion. For instance, consider the power series ring $F[[x]]$ over your favorite field $F$. This ring is not Artinian, since $$(x)\supset(x^2)\supset(x^3)\supset\dots$$ is an infinite descending chain. But the ring is local, with maximal ideal and thus Jacobson radical $(x)$, and $F[[x]]\big/(x)\cong F$ is simple, hence semisimple.

Comment: Nice solution. I should have thought of moving on from polynomial ring to power series ring.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person my pleasure, happy it helped! :)